# Update dictionary key(s) by drop starts with value from key in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary `dict`:

```
dict = {'drop_key1': '10001', 'drop_key2':'10002'}
```

The key(s) in `dict` startswith `drop_`, i would like to update `dict` by dropping `drop_` value from key(s):

```
dict = {'key1': '10001', 'key2':'10002'}
```

What is the best approach to do it?

Comment: @yatu: No, that's totally wrong. That will remove all leading and trailing characters in the set `{'d', 'r', 'o', 'p', '_'}`. `"drop_prod_foo_pro".strip('drop_')` is just `"f"` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
d1 = {'drop_key1': '10001', 'drop_key2':'10002'}
d2 = {k[5:]:v for k,v in d1.items()}
print(d2)
```

output

```
{'key1': '10001', 'key2': '10002'}
```

Comment: @yatu Read the question again: "... The key(s) in dict startswith drop_ ...."

Comment: *Read the question again*.... eh okay... Only a suggestion, missed that part

Answer (score 1):

One approach is, for each `key` value in the dictionary, you can replace  the part of the string with the new string value. For instance:

```py
d = {k.replace('drop_', ''): v for k, v in d.items() if k.strip().startswith('drop_')}
```

or you can define a function, and get the index of the searched string ("`drop_`"). If the search string index is 0, then remove it. For instance:

```py
def change_key(key, search):
    start_idx = key.find(search)
    if start_idx == 0:
        key = key.replace(search, "")
    return key

d = {change_key(k, search="drop_"): v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Result:

```py
{'key1': '10001', 'key2': '10002'}
```

Note that if you use a method, then you can guarantee to remove the search string if it is at the beginning of the string. For instance:

```py
d = {'      drop_key1': '10001', 'drop_key2': '10002'}
d = {change_key(k, search="drop_"): v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Result:

```
{'      drop_key1': '10001', 'key2': '10002'}
```

Comment: This will also replace the sub-string `"drop_"` on positions other than the beginning.

Comment: Your new version will also change keys of the form `"     drop_Foo"` which technically it also should not. Additionally, it will change `"drop_drop_foodrop_"` to `"foo"` which is wrong.

Comment: But why would you write `key` value as `"      drop_Foo"` ?

Comment: That's the wrong approach to programming. In the real world all kinds of problems will eventually arise if you don't pay attention to corner cases. Given that some people might just copy&paste your answer, using it for their related problem, it should exactly adhere to the specification. The second problem I mentioned (multiple occurrences of `"drop_"` in a string starting with `"drop_"`) is much more likely to happen though.

Comment: You could probably combine barderman's approach, i.e. slicing, with the check using `startswith`. I don't think we need to contemplate absolutely all edge cases, we don't know the particularities of op's problem. Although as far as the specs go, baldernam's approach is enough, since apparently all keys start by that substring `drop_`. In such case, no stripping is needed